# Alter data returned by http using map method in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I have written code like below

```
getCalculatedValuesViaGet  = (myData): Observable < RmdResponse > => {
    return this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                          { headers: this.getHeaders })
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .map(x => { x.title = x.title + "hello world" })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Basically i want to append some extra info to each object returned from http method. My understanding is that first map converts it to JSON object. Second object should pass each object inside array and make the updation. But whole object is passed to second map method rather than each individual object. Looks like my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your service is actually returning an array, you should use either `.forEach` or `.map` to transform each individual object:

```js
getCalculatedValuesViaGet = (myData): Observable<RmdResponse> => {
    return this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        {headers: this.getHeaders})
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        //the following x contains an array of objects, map to transform the data
        .map(x => {
                //this map is the function of array, not Observable.
                //iterate through each object, and update the value of `title`
                return x.map(y => Object.assign(y, {title: y.title + 'hello world'}))
            }
        )
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```